# "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" error on using wordcloud in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, word-cloud

I installed the word cloud library in python to use wordcloud. I am able to successfully use it in all editors like sublime, etc but when I am trying to use it in Jupyter notebook then it is giving me error:
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

I have been trying to solve this issue from last 2 days but not getting success. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too faced this issue.
the problem was when wordcloud is installed it gets python modules and stores in 
**C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages** folder (in my case this is the python executable path this may vary for you) so when you import from jupyter it tries to find it in this path , but wordcloud creates one more folder with same name and downloads all wordcloud module in side this , this is one more level in directory so jupyter is unable to find. so the hack what i did is copied all modules from inner wordclod folder to one level outside i.e

> copy all from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud ->
>   C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wordcloud

so this made the trick and no more error.

Comment: Hello Naveen, Thanks for the help but it did not work.

Comment: C:\Users\ankit\Anaconda3\pkgs\wordcloud-1.4.1-py36_0\Lib\site-packages
At this location I have two folders: wordcloud and wordcloud-1.4.1.dist-info
I copied all the content inside wordcloud folder to location
C:\Users\ankit\Anaconda3\pkgs\wordcloud-1.4.1-py36_0\Lib\site-packages
But it did not work

Comment: @bisht if you are installing wordcloud via anaconda then try creating a virtual environment and install wordcloud  inside it  and check in jupyter notebook this will work for sure. [conda env] (https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)